# Split video in iMovie 10.1.1

Tags: imovie

I have a 45-minute long video; I've split it into about 20 segments (things separated by a black vertical bar in the timeline, produced using the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>  "Split clip" operation).

I'd now like to export each of these, but when I select one and go to "Share...", iMovie seems to want to export the whole 45 minute video.

Can someone suggest a way to export just one of these 2-minute clips/segments/whatever-they're-called?

I ask in advance: please explain in the most pedestrian terms -- I've used iMovie for about 45 minutes so far, and a moment ago I had to look up "where is the 'Project Window' in iMovie." That shoudl give you some idea of the depths of my ignorance.

(I did a pretty extensive web search on this, with no luck, partly because this has been asked lots of times, and there are answers for many versions of iMovie, which all seem to have inconsistent naming conventions, like version 9.something being called "iMovie 11", etc.  I'm sure the answer's out there somewhere, but my search-fu was not strong enough...)

Comment: Answered! Let me know by commenting below my answer whether it helps, and do tell me if you need more help with iMovie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iMovie is a little weird about exporting individual video clips. Here's a great workaround:

1. Select a clip you want to export, then copy it with Command-C.
2. Open another window of iMovie, and in that new window, create a new project. Paste this clip into that new project.
3. Then export that new project with Command-E.

Now you've got that clip alone!

Comment: Wow. So much for "it just works". Thank heavens there are scripting tools like Sikuli, since I have a whole bunch of these to do. :(

Comment: @John Glad I (and other tools!) can help.

Comment: I'm using version 10.2.1 and I don't see how to open a new window. Is it possible in this version?