# How to split a video exported from iMovie into multiple shorter videos

Tags: imovie, video-editing

I have several movies that have been exported from iMovie in the mp4 format. I would like to split each of these movies into five segments, ideally without messing with the video quality/compression settings. Is there an easy piece of software that I could use to do this easialy?

By the way, I know I can [copy clips into other projects](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245269/split-video-in-imovie-10-1-1) in iMovie and create individual segments that way, but due to complicated timings and the large number of times I need to do this, I would really rather have some piece of software that could do this with less fussiness. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickTime Player Version 10.5 has a trim feature (command+T) that allows for this exact functionality.